# What is the alternative to none() step in gremlin cosmos db?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

We are looking for a `none()` step alternative as our Gremlin compliant queries use a `none()` step but Cosmos throws a "'none' step not recognized error".

Since Cosmos supports String based queries while adding a Vertex in Java using the `.iterate()` method, on the Gremlin traversal a `none()` step gets added, which is not supported in Cosmos . Is there any alternative to the `none()` step? Can we use `.toList()` instead of `.iterate()` on the traversal?

Answer (score 0):

The `iterate` terminal step just tells Gremlin to run the query but not return any results. Under the covers, this adds an implicit `none` step to the query. It should be fine to use any other terminal step that your particular backend implementation can handle. Using `toList` will iterate the traversal and also return any results generated by the query in a list. If there are no results, an empty list `[]` will be returned and your code should check for that case.